# Пропадает галочка при проверке checkbox на checked

Tags: checkbox

Доброго времени суток!
Такая задача - нужно, чтобы при проставлении галочки в чекбоксе, появлялось скрытое поле. Всё это я реализовал, но проблема в том, что галочка не проставляется. В чём причина?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="promo" action="">
        <div class="check_wrap">
            <span>промо-код</span>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                Использовать промокод
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="code">
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


    $(".check").on("click", function(){    
    if($(".check").prop("checked") != 'checked') { 
        $(".code").toggleClass('visibility');
        return false;
    }
        return true;
});
```

Comment: зачем return false; ?

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `return` из обработчика. И проверяйте `checked` вот так:

```js
$(".check").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(".check").prop("checked"));
  if ($(".check").prop("checked")) {
    $(".code").show();
  } else {
    $(".code").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="check_wrap">
  <span>промо-код</span>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    Использовать промокод
  </label>
</div>
<input type="text" class="code" style="display:none">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```